# How to change ChromeCustomTab Toolbar Title?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I've been reading about ChromeCustomTab and I've been wondering, is there a way to change the title text in the toolbar? I've seen the option to change the color and to hide the text, but I've yet to see something like `toolbar.setTitle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand your question, but if you mean to show anotherthing instead the URL or Page name, I know that is not possible to hide url, I read a idea to hide it here: [how to hide the URL Of Custom Tab in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213314/how-to-hide-the-url-of-custom-tab-in-android)

Comment: I actually meant edit the URL to show instead my own custom title. What you sent works too though.

Comment: builder.enableUrlBarHiding()