# How to hide the URL Of Custom Tab?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am using a custom tab in android. I have gone through many of the google search to hide the URL of custom tab but everywhere is showing that it is not possible to hide the URL.I just want to know that is there any way from which i can hide the url in custom tab.

[image: The url of my app]

Comment: probably it is defined in your Strings.xml under values folder so you should search there for this occurance and then delete it or extract a new String which isn't used as a Toolbar title.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this ugly solution which can do the trick while you don't get a better solution:

1) create an html document with this contents:

```
<frameset rows="100%">
     <frameset cols="100%">
          <frame src="http://192.169.218.96:7777" frameborder="0">
     </frameset>
</frameset>
```

2) save this on your **ASSETS** folder (same level as **RES** and not inside it). Trying to illustrate this:

```
+ src
++ main
+++ assets
+++ java
+++ res
```

3) make your customTab load this asset instead of the original url (you could implement a connectivity detector here to show alternative content if internet is not present).

EDIT: 4) then use this string on your custom tab loading method (considering you saved your frameset html with name of **name.html**):

```
String loadPage = "file:///android_asset/name.html";
```

Do not use the common html, head, body (and so on) tags, just what I've showed above.

Old but fully compliant with W3C and browsers solution. Details: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/present/frames.html#h-16.2.1

Comment: where to use frameset in res folder or any where else

Comment: Item 2) on my answer. If ASSETS folder doesn't exists you create it.

Comment: can you tell me how can i call this file in custom tab please

Comment: Excuse me: have forgotten about it. Edited my answer to reflect this.